# Che cosa significa «le reni quasi ingommate»?

Tags: word-meaning

C'è un brano nel romanzo «Il fu Mattia Pascal» da Luigi Pirandello:

> Già ad Alenga, per cominciare, ero entrato, poche ore prima di partire, da un barbiere, per farmi accorciar la barba: avrei voluto levarmela tutta, lì stesso, insieme coi baffi; ma il timore di far nascere qualche sospetto in quel piccolo paese mi aveva trattenuto.
>
> Il barbiere era anche sartore, vecchio, **con le reni quasi ingommate** dalla lunga abitudine di star curvo, sempre in una stessa positura, e portava gli occhiali su la punta del naso. Più che barbiere doveva esser sartore. Calò come un flagello di Dio su quella barbaccia che non m’apparteneva più, armato di certi forbicioni da maestro di lana, che avevan bisogno d’esser sorretti in punta con l’altra mano.

Cosa sono «le reni ingommate»? Credo che non c'entri la colla, come [suggerisce](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/ingommare) il *Treccani*. Significa piuttosto che le reni del barbiere sono come un caucciù, molto mobili?

Grazie!

Comment: I think it's the immagine of someone who has osteoarthritis in such a way that he has lumbar vertebrae as if they were stuck together.

Comment: Penso che questo barbiere probabilmente soffra di artrosi e per questa ragione ha le vertebre lumbari come se fossero incollate tra loro.

Comment: @Charo, grazie, questa spiegazione sembra logica.

Comment: Se ti sembra bene, cerco di metterlo come risposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mia interpretazione è che questo vecchio barbiere probabilmente soffra di artrosi e, per questa ragione, abbia le vertebre lumbari come se fossero incollate tra loro. Questo fatto e l'abitudine, a causa del suo mestiere, di essere quasi sempre nella stessa postura lo rendono ricurvo.

Answer (score 0):

Il significato è quello che le reni del barbiere/sartore erano ingommate cioè, metaforicamente, era come se fossero state spalmate di gomma in modo da renderle flessibili come il caucciù.

Infatti l’abitudine alla postura avevano dato alla sua schiena una resistenza e flessibilità non comuni.

Comment: “Star curvo, sempre in una stessa positura” non dà esattamente l'idea di una “resistenza e flessibilità non comuni”...

Comment: Intendevo che una persona normale si spezzerebbe la schiena mentre il suo “allenamento” le ha rese flessibili